# How to organise sql data into order with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm tryign to organise some data from a database using PHP and MySQL.

I want to display a list of company locations and their respective child departments, buildings etc.

But I cant seem to organise the data properly, and I cant get my head around how it should be done.

So, the hierarchy could get quite complex, with 7 different levels, and many branches off each.

I have tried lumping all the data in a single table, but I cant get the areas to group properly.

I need to display the data as per the below:

**Top Level[North] - (Company region)**

-2nd level[Newcastle] - (region location)

--3rd level[End Building] - (loction Building)

---4th level[Accounts] - (building department)

----5th level[FD office] - (department office)

---4th level[Admin] - (building department)

----5th level[OM office] - (department office)

-2nd level[Aberdeen] - (region location)

--3rd level[Green Building] - (location building)

--- 4th level[science] - (building department)

So, whats the best way to organise this so that I can group each level together with its children levels?

My thinking is to have each level in a database table, and then have another table which links the levels and their children, but I cannot get my head around how to organise it and get the data out.

Can you shed any light on the best way?

Heres the single table I am trying

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the simplest approach is to store all the data in one table, with a "parent" field, refering to the id of it's parent level. Null is it's a root/top level entry.

This can be done this way :

```
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) !== false) {
    if ($row['parent_id'] !== null) {
        $index[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
    } else {
        $topLevel = $row;
    }
}

function displayChildren($level_id, $index) {
    foreach ($index as $children) {

        usort($children, function($a, $b) {
            return $a['level'] - $b['level'];
        });

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child['parent_id'] == $level_id) {
                echo str_repeat('-', $child['level']);
                echo $child['name'];
                echo "<br />";
                displayChildren($child['id'], $index);
            }
        }
    }
}

displayChildren($topLevel['id'], $index);
```

This code implies a random order within the same level, and a level field in your database. Tune the code to fit your needs perfectly :)

Comment: Yeah thats how I tried it, but how do I organise the data so that I can group all levels with their children?

Comment: You cannot do that with MySQL. Some RDBMS such as PostGreSQL can do this kind of request. For you case, you will have to use PHP to build your tree.

Comment: OK, how can i group them together with php, thats the issue im having, grouping the levels and their children together

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this create a table-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `level` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test_table`
--

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`, `level`) VALUES
(1, 'root1', 0, 0),
(2, 'root2', 0, 0),
(3, 'root1-level1', 1, 1),
(4, 'root1-level2', 1, 2),
(5, 'root2-level2', 2, 1),
(6, 'root2-level3', 2, 2);
```

After creation you can get the data by using self join-

```
select t1.name as parent_name, t2.name, t2.level from test_table t1 join test_table t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id order by t1.id
```

Comment: Yeah that doesnt work, its not sorting the parents with their children